# scipy savemat fails under [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have an array `f` whose shape is `(100, 2, 3, 56730, 10, 1)`
when I try to save it with `savemat('file.mat', dict(f=f))` I get the error

```
    475 
    476     def write_bytes(self, arr):
--> 477         self.file_stream.write(arr.tostring(order='F'))
    478 
    479     def write_string(self, s):

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

but not when I run `savemat('file.mat', dict(f=[0, 1, 2))`

Is this because my variable f is too big?
For the record `firingRates.nbytes` is `2723040000`

which I guess it means it is around 2GB

Comment: It could mean that `file_stream.write()` expects a `bytes` object instead of a string. You can easily verify if size is the issue by saving a smaller array. See [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That's from the operation system (OSError); Since it occurs in a code that routinely works, array being to big is the most likely possibility.  At this point it is writing the `raw` databuffer bytes to the file.  I'd try slices of this array, and may be do `x = f.tostring(order='F')` just to prove that step is ok.

Comment: I came upon the exact same error, and it was indeed due to the variable (`f` in the example above) being too big. Available memory was not a limitation. In my case, I could afford a lost of precision so it was enough to convert from `float64` to `float32`.